# Cleaning a Torah Scroll

Tags: how-to, sefer-torah, cleaning

Our shul recently had a sofer in to look at our newer Torah scroll.  He suggested to the Rabbi that we clean the scrolls regularly, which we have never done.  So we did it a few days ago, about 20 of us cleaning 2 scrolls.

The sofer told us to use facial tissue (Kleenex), which we did.  We gently wiped all parts of the text and the white space.  As we rolled them up, we wiped the back of the scrolls too.  Lots of dust!!

I found, and others agreed, that the tissues broke apart, leaving both bits of tissue and a fair bit of lint, even though we changed them frequently.   We didn't damage the scrolls.  So I wonder if there are better things to use.  A soft cloth?  Even a soft brush for the backs and/or as a final step after rubbing the text side.

Our scrolls:
1) 200-300 years old, deerskin vellum, some damage. Tissues didn't make much noticeable difference but did remove dust.
2) 100 years old, cow vellum, in good shape.  Tissues brightened the pages noticeably and removed dust.

We plan to do this again in about a year and will research alternative materials.  We're on the West Coast of the US but the Rabbi and others regularly travel to Israel and elsewhere so we can easily get products if needed.

What does your shul use?

Comment: I would recommend using a microfiber cloth.

Comment: Maybe just pressurized air?

Comment: anti-static cloth -- https://www.amazon.com/Kinetronics-Anti-static-Microfiber-Cloth-10x18-Inch/dp/B00009R7VT

Comment: What is the benefit of cleaning the scrolls (besides the evident risk of making them invalid)?

Comment: @Kazibácsi it sounds like it makes them easier to read.  I hope a sofer will weigh in on this question.

Comment: Apparently, the backs of the scrolls tend to flake off over time, creating dust.  It's minute, but adds up over time.  I could see for myself how the text of our newer scroll visibly darkened after a swipe with the tissue.  The vellum also brightened a bit.  With the older scroll, there was just as much dust, but the visible changes were slight.  We were told that this cleaning helps preserve the scrolls as well.  It's apparently part of maintenance.  We didn't know!

Comment: This is a great practical question for me. I'm our shul's Torah reader, not the Torah care-taker. But, as I read from these "beauties" each week (some seforim more frequently than others), I like to keep them in good shape. I'll ask around, and I hope that in addition to finding something to clean it, maybe someone could recommend a product to keep it smelling less "foul" and perhaps prevent the musty smell, to a degree. It's inevitable that old shuls such as mine don't have the best "weather environment" for Sifrei Torah. Maybe, I will ask a related question.

Comment: "deerskin vellum" - I gather that these are rare to find. If I'm out on the West Coast, I would consider visiting your shul just to see these.

Comment: DanF: Yes, deerskin vellum seems to be very rare.  Fortunately, our Torah scrolls don't have any must or other odor.  But we don't have high humidity here.  You would be welcome to visit our shul (north of San Francisco) but please keep in mind that we are not Orthodox; it is Reconstructionist.

Comment: @ezra, that might be a bit too course for a Torah

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt You can get different grades. There are industrial cleaning microfibers down to the kind you clean glasses with, and even softer than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I relayed your question to the *sofer* who maintains our scrolls.  Here's what he said (my notes from a verbal conversation):

The "dust" that came off of the scroll is white mold, not the parchment flaking off.  (Not all mold is black.)  You should therefore clean your scrolls in a well-ventilated place and consider wearing a mask.  Because he does this a lot he has a high-end mask with good filters, but for people doing this rarely, the inexpensive disposable masks are fine.

Use a clean, soft, white cloth to clean the scrolls.  He suggested that you buy a new towel and use it only for this purpose.  White is important to avoid any chance of the scroll picking up dyes.  The mold attaches to both the parchment and the ink, so wipe everything.

I didn't ask about using tissues, but it sounds like a false economy -- a decent towel doesn't cost that much, and towels don't fall apart the way tissues do.

Comment: Great info, thank you. Mold ugh. We're in a building over 100 years old so mold is already an issue (though we have only moderate humidity and don't get the must smell that DanF is dealing with).  It was a large room with high ceilings and windows that open and we were running two air filters (both HEPA and carbon together).  I own an industrial mask but didn't think to use it or any other.

Comment: @Cyn from my conversation it sounded like this is a common problem, perhaps the norm unless you take extraordinary steps in humidity control (like museums do).  We have scrolls that are kept wrapped up except when briefly opened to a few columns to be read one or a few times a week.  They never get the chance to get aired out.